# Possible ways to implement voice recording functionality without flash

Tags: html, html5-audio, audio-recording, voice

I know it would be hard to implement a web-based voice recorder without using flash, but is there any existing API that could help make this possible to achieve? Is HTML5 media feature matured enough for this space?

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1):

[Web Audio API](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/) is quite mature, and [supported by many browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api) (even on mobile).
You can implement your audio recorder starting from

- [this example](http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html)
- [this plugin](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs)